# Required tools to work through the book "Introduction to Assesmbly Language Programming"?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Ok, the full title of the book is:
Introduction to Assembly Language Programming For Pentium and RISC Processors by Sivarama P. Dandamudi (second edition)
I borrowed the book from a friend and it has been quite some time since he read it, he doesn't do any assembly (he likes collecting books) and can't remember what he used when he read it. Near the very beginning of the book the author states that NASM will be used and not MASM. So I grabbed the latest stable release. There is a link given which 'should' lead to a place where you can download the required software to complete the material presented in the book, unfortunately, it's dead. I went to the parent site of the link but couldn't really find anything helpful (it's a university website). So I am hoping that someone here has read this book and can lead me to the required tools to run on a Windows 7 system?? 
I am just a hobbyist programmer. I am quite familiar with VB.NET and recently decided that it might be a good idea to expand my knowledge to different languages. NOt just for versatility but I am hoping that seeing 
things from lots of different approaches will give me a greater understanding of programming in general.
This is the part where I will likely be ridiculed and told that I am taking the wrong approach but here goes.... Over the last 5 or 6 months I have been dabbling in a few different languages. I have been told I am making a big mistake and I should stick to one language at a time and learn that back-to-front, inside-and-out. But I felt that because I already understand the fundamentals of object oriented programming in a high-level language (VB.NET) that what I could do is take a piece of information from here and a snippet of code from there and combine them to form a greater understanding in my mind. Recently I began my journey into C and C++ and it occured to me that to TRULY understand the fine art of computer programming I might need to get down and dirty and crawl through the primordial sludge of a lower-level language and it is to this end that I have seized the afore-mentioned piece of literature from the talons of a relentless horder and collector and 
hope to put it to good use.
Ultimately I am hoping that I can use an environment I am already somewhat familiar with...
Currently, the Languages and IDE's I am using are :
For VB and C# - of course, Visual Studio 2013.
For Java - Eclipse or Netbeans.
For Python - Visual Studio or Eclipse.
For C and C++ - Eclipse or NetBeans and sometimes I mess around with Visual Studio. (with Eclipse and NetBeans I am using the mingw complier)

What are my options here (if any)? I know that NetBeans supports Assembly but I don't know if it is NASM? And from what I have read the syntax is quite different between the different types of ASM (please correct me if I am wrong) I have been told that Visual Studio will only do MASM (again please correct me if need be) and the book I have to work with clearly states from the onset that MASM will not be used..

Sorry for the lengthy rambling. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you have even a shred of doubt about a book, why not toss it?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I don't really have much else to go off, this is the only book I could get my hands on for learning asm. I have heard good things about the book. I don't really "doubt" the books capability of teaching me something, I am just wondering how to get the ball rolling with the software I already have (if possible) or what I should install if that is not possible.

Comment: As to "getting your hands on": [Bartlett](ftp://gnu.mirrors.pair.com/savannah/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-lettersize.pdf)'s book is gnu-licensed free online. It uses as and Linux, so is not ideal for you, and is very elementary (but good for what it means to do). Just in case you'd like to compare a concept with how it's presented in your book.

Answer (score 0):

You can download NASM from here

http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/?C=M;O=D

I am not sure if you are trying Win 32 Assembly or old days DOS assembly programs (not aware of that book).

For DOS assembly, you can download a DOS emulator called DOSBOX

http://www.dosbox.com/

There is even a portable version here:
http://portableapps.com/apps/games/dosbox_portable

Comment: Yes I have DOSBOX, lol, for playing old DOS games when I feel nostalgic. I am looking at Win32 assembly though.

Comment: For Win32 Assemblyh, I would recommend MASM and Iczelion tutorials http://win32assembly.programminghorizon.com/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the link to an open source x86 assembler is here http://www.nasm.us. Note that your question is not really specific to a programming issue specifically so you are unlikely to get many more responses to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read Dr. Dandamudi's book, but I do have a version of his libraries. What I have is for Linux and probably wouldn't help you. I don't recall where I got it - as you say, it was a University site - "Carleton.ca" perhaps. I think I just googled for his name. Ah, is this it?

http://www.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/org_book/org_book_web/source_code.html